# Android Studio : No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: android-studio, android-resources

I can't fix this error in Android Studio.

This is a picture showing the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove hardware acceleration attributes from your manifest.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated='false'
```

or support an API level less than 11

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Comment: Thanks bro,
I did what you told me, but still the same error